CoreWCF conversion is working fine but after making exe file but doesn't get launched
I just converted WCF ServiceHost to CoreWCF. After that when I prepared the exe file, I could not launch the exe and start the process. I tried with below:
public WebApplication CreateHost()
 {

     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
         builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices();
         builder.Services.AddServiceModelMetadata();
         builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior,           UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();
        
         var app = builder.Build();
 
         app.UseServiceModel(serviceBuilder =>
         {
            
             serviceBuilder.AddService<MaintenanceService>();
             serviceBuilder.AddServiceEndpoint<TestService, ITestService>(TestSettings.BINDING, TestSettings.ADDRESS);
             serviceBuilder.ConfigureServiceHostBase<ITestService>(serviceHost =>
             {
                 var behavior = new ServiceBehaviorAttribute();
                 behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
                 behavior.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple;
                 serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
                 
             });

         });
   
         app.StartAsync();
         return app;
}
public static class TestSettings
{
    public const string SERVICE_NAME = "Test";
    public const string ADDRESS = "net.pipe://localhost/test/maintenance";
    public static readonly Binding BINDING = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None) { ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue, CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue, SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue };
    
}

This TestSettings also used in Client which are using ServiceModel. Now problem is that if I create an exe file for server and install it, it wont install and run as a service. It wont launch. I used below :
var path = @"Dir"
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
p.StartInfo.FileName = path + "\Test.exe";
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-install";
await Task.Run(() =>
{ 
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
});

If I manually install using SC Create command it could install but not start.
Gives the below error:
Windows could not  start the Test Service on Local Computer.
Error 1053: The Service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
I have seen similar issue but did not mention how he solved.
I have checked the old WCF(System.ServiceModel) is working fine if I create the exe and install as a service. It could launch easily.

In general, there are many asynchronous operations in Core. Then the Windows service has a time limit when it starts, which can cause a timeout error if your service doesn't fully start within that time. You can try it in the app. StartAsync() is followed by the await keyword to ensure that the method waits correctly for completion during the startup process. await app.StartAsync(); I also recommend that you add a log to see it in action. Tracing and Message Logging

Thanks. I have tried with the change but no impact. Same result

I was able to solve this issue by adding the following code before calling .Build();
builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
     options.ServiceName = "Service Name";
});

e.g.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices();
builder.Services.AddServiceModelMetadata();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior, UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();
    
builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
     options.ServiceName = "Service Name";
});

var app = builder.Build();

Which I got from this Microsoft page on creating a windows service with dotnet core.

Thank you @lanith. I added it but I found the reason. As I am using a webservice to host the WCF in .netframework. Now it is different for CoreWCF. Also, one thing is that CoreWCF is based ASP.net core which also have own host. Need to look how to host CoreWCF. or how to use those webservice method(OnStart, Onstop, etc) in new CoreWCF. Did you use any webservice for the CoreWCF? I am trying to get samples.
